# setting an end of char* manually doesn't work

Tags: c++, null, char

I wrote this short program

```
int main(){
    char * c = "abcd";
    c[1] = '\0';
    cout << c << endl;
}
```

and it doesn't work... actually it compiles the program but in the runtime an error occures...
Why? I thought it will print an "a" as the "string" now looks like this: "a0cd" so after a zero it is supposed to detect an end of the string, right? So where is the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't modify string literals like that.

Try this instead:

```
int main(){
    char c[] = "abcd";
    c[1] = '\0';
    cout << c << endl;
}
```

The reason behind this is that string literals are stored in global memory (often in a read-only segment). Modifying them is undefined behavior. However, if you initialize it as an array `char c[] = "abcd"` it will be on the stack (as opposed to global memory), so you can freely modify it.

Comment: thank you. So what exactly was the problem? Do  you know the underlying reason why not?

Comment: The C standard has nothing to say about stacks and global memory, that's an implementation issue. It should be sufficient to state the the standard disallows modifying string literals.

Answer (score 1):

if you use C++ why not use [std::string::substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main () {
  std::string c = "abcd";
  std::string d = c.substr(0,2);
  std::cout << d << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

the output of the program:

```
 ab
```

Comment: yeah, I know it works like that too, but I really wanted to try it "the low level way" to see how it actually works in the core of the language...

Comment: @Tomy: interesting because 95% of the people think that std::string is one of the major reasons to skip c for C++. string manipulation is mostly not time critical and the C string api is pretty obscure.

Comment: well actually I DO code in C++ and I DO use std::string - my question was just out of curiosity - nothing more :) thanks anyway